# Why is the yield keyword used in conjunction with return and break, and not by itself?

Tags: c#

In C# you can construct methods with the return type of `IEnumerable<T>` and use `yield return` and `yield break` to control the flow. Here is a simple example that uses both controls:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetEvens(int start, int end) {
    if(end < start)
        yield break;

    if(start & 2 != 0)
        start++;

    for(int i = start; i <= end; i+=2) {
        yield return i;
    }        
}
```

My question is, why was it originally designed to use two keywords with `yield` and not use it like the following with the single `yield` "yielding the return value":

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetEvens(int start, int end) {
    if(end < start)
        return; // stop completely and return nothing

    if(start & 2 != 0)
        start++;

    for(int i = start; i <= end; i+=2) {
        yield i; // yield the current value.
    }        
}
```

To me, this is simpler to read and understand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The slightly awkward `yield return` syntax was created [so that existing code that used the word "yield" as an identifier (variable name) would not break](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/why-yield-return-rather-than-yield).  (It makes perfect sense, for example, to have a variable named `yield` if you're working with financial code.)  Since "yield return" would have been a syntax error back then, the new syntax would not break any existing code.

As for `yield break`, no idea.  That really doesn't seem to have any good reason behind it that I can find.

Comment: Wouldn't `yield x;` also of been a syntax error back then?

Comment: @Moop: By making it `yield` `return`, you don't even have to bother thinking about whether it was a syntax error or not.  The chance of a collision becomes zero.

Comment: For "yield break;", it's essentially like "return;" in a void method, but using "return;" in combination with "yield return;" could be confusing. So the choice of "yield break" is a consequence of choosing "yield return".

Comment: @Moop But `yield(x)` could have been valid code.

Comment: @Moop: Point is that `yield = 4` was perfectly valid but making `yield` a keyword would have made it invalid. Making `yield return` a keyword couldn't break any existing code, because nothing with yield and return together like that could ever have compiled.

Comment: @Moop if you had a type named `yield` then `yield x;` would not be a syntax error, but a valid variable declaration.

Comment: @Moop: What if you had a function named `yield` that took a single parameter?

Comment: @moop: See also http://ericlippert.com/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/27/ambiguous-optional-parentheses-part-three.aspx if the subject of introducing new keywords without breaking any code interests you.